# How do I move rows to columns for ever n rows?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a 1 column pandas df like:

```
[col1]
area123
account,time,day,total,users
code1,50s,monday,5,6
code2,40s,monday,5,6
area234
account,time,day,total,users
code5,20s,monday,4,9
code2,40s,monday,2,6
area26
.
.
.
```

How do I seperate it to multiple rows with a new colum for area so it looks like:

```
enter code here

[area]     [account]    [time]    [day]   [totals]   [users]
 area123     code1        50s     monday    5          6
 area123     code2        40s     monday    5          6
 area234     code5        20s     monday    4          9
 area234     code2       40s      monday    2          6
    .          .          .          .      .          .
    .          .          .          .      .          .
```

Note: the data repeats this structure every 4 rows and the column names are in every second row,  every 3rd row is the values split by a comma.  So every area should be converted to just 2 row.

I was thinking using regex to split the data by the string 'area' or something.

Any help or direction would be great.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `numpy array` by modulo first.

- [`insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) new column in first position with area values created by [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) and [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with method `ffill`
- remove rows with 2,3 by [`numpy.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)
- remove column by [`pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) and create new columns by [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html)

---

```
a = np.arange(len(df.index)) % 4
print (a)
[0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0]

df.insert(0, 'area', df['col'].mask(a != 0).ffill())
df = df[np.in1d(a, [2,3])].reset_index(drop=True)
df[['account','time','day','total', 'users']] = df.pop('col').str.split(',', expand=True)
print (df)

      area account time     day total users
0  area123   code1  50s  monday     5     6
1  area123   code2  40s  monday     5     6
2  area234   code5  20s  monday     4     9
3  area234   code2  40s  monday     2     6
```

More general solution:

```
mask = df['col'].str.contains(',')
df.insert(0, 'area', df['col'].mask(mask).ffill())
df = df.iloc[0:]
df = df[~((df['col'] == df['area'])|df['col'].str.contains('account,time,day,total,users'))]
df[['account','time','day','total', 'users']] = df.pop('col').str.split(',', expand=True)
print (df)
      area account time     day total users
2  area123   code1  50s  monday     5     6
3  area123   code2  40s  monday     5     6
6  area234   code5  20s  monday     4     9
7  area234   code2  40s  monday     2     6
```

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware of mask

Answer (score 1):

`numpy` manipulation

```
from numpy.core.defchararray import split as csplit

c = df.col1.values

i = pd.Index(c[::4].repeat(len(c) // 4), name='area')
j = csplit(c[1], ',').tolist()
v = csplit(c.reshape(-1, 2)[1::2].ravel().astype(str), ',').tolist()

pd.DataFrame(v, i, j).reset_index()

      area account time     day total users
0  area123   code1  50s  monday     5     6
1  area123   code2  40s  monday     5     6
2  area234   code5  20s  monday     4     9
3  area234   code2  40s  monday     2     6
```